# Android: change background of ImageButton dynamically and show it

Tags: android, background, imagebutton, invalidation

I implemented ArrayAdapter for `ListView`, where each row contains `TextView` and `ImageButton`. 
The background image of ImageButton depends on some condition, two options are available:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_with_button, null);

            File f = new File(PATH_TO_FILE);
            if(f.exists()){
                imbutton =(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_image);
                imbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.done);
            }else
            {
                imbutton =(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_image);
                imbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
                imbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String url = URL;
                        new DownloadFileAsync(pos).execute(url);
                    }
                });
            }
... 
return vi;
}
```

If file exists, then I set "done" image on ImageButton. If file doesn't exist, I set "download" image.

After user clicks on `ImageButton`, the file downloads and I need change respective image.
The problem is that `getView` is called only if user scrolls `ListView` down  until this `ImageButton` dissapear from the screen and then scroll back. After that button appears with new background image.

However, I can't invalidate button to display new image at the moment.

I used this class for async downloading: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521

I tried make something like `currentbutton.invalidate()` in function

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
       activity.dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
```

but without success.

How can I invalidate `ImageButton` to display its new background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) in the onClick listener to force a refresh on the list.
I haven't tried it though, so I'm not sure if it'll work without making any explicit changes on the adapter(i.e. adding, removing or updating items on it).

I'll check it later and write any further suggestions if it doesn't work out of the box.

EDIT: Actually you need to call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask you are using, not in the onClick listener.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

And after press the button load the image to a specific ImageView with you reference in getView.

Comment: My arrayAdapter is modified LazyAdapter. It loads images properly, the problem is in dynamic changing of image and invalidating

Answer (score 0):

you can try pass to your `AsyncTask` , the `Button` view clicked to your `AsyncTask` :

```
new DownloadFileAsync(imButton).execute(url);
```

and then , in your method `onPostExecute()` , you can call :

```
this.btnClicked.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.done);
```

Comment: I tried, but button didn't invalidate. I suppose `getView` method should be programmatically called by some way for this..